# Contexts in which pack expansions can occur

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

There is a clear and comprehensible list of contexts in which a pack expansion can occur on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). What I am trying to do is to derive the same information from the standard, partly to gain experience in using the standard. However, I am unable to derive all pack expansion contexts listed on cppreference.com from the standard.

cppreference.com lists, among others, the following four contexts: function argument lists, template argument lists, function parameter lists and template parameter lists.

On the other hand, the standard says (14.5.3.4):

> A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends on the context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> - In a function parameter pack (8.3.5); the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis.
> - In a template parameter pack that is a pack expansion (14.1):
>
>   - if the template parameter pack is a parameter-declaration; the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis;
>   - if the template parameter pack is a type-parameter with a template-parameter-list; the pattern is the corresponding type-parameter without the ellipsis.
> - ...
> - In a template-argument-list (14.3); the pattern is a template-argument.
> - ...

I am unable to find out where the standard says that pack expansion can occur in function argument lists. I suppose this context is somehow covered by one of the three bullet points quoted above.

Just in case it is unclear what I mean by pack expansions in function argument lists, consider the following example:

```
template <typename ...Args> void f(Args ...args) {}
template <typename ...Args> void g(Args ...args) {
  f(args...); // Pack expansion in a function argument list.
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when a function is being invoked? E.g. `f(some_pack...)`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Exactly, see also the [cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) mentioned in the question. I am talking about the examples below the heading "Function argument lists".

Comment: possible complete explanation here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack see "expansion loci"

Comment: @RichardHodges ...did you read the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function argument list is syntactically an *initializer-list*<sup>1</sup>, so it's covered by [[temp.variadic]/(4.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#4.4):

> In an *initializer-list*; the pattern is an *initializer-clause*.

---

<sub>1. The grammar of a function call is *postfix-expression* **(** *expression-list*<sub>opt</sub> **)**. And an *expression-list* is just an *initializer-list*. ([[expr.post]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post))</sub>